# Which free embedded web server can handle *REALLY LARGE* POST requests?

Tags: post, file-upload, webserver, embedded-linux, large-files

I have an embedded Linux device without a huge amount of RAM but a decent amount of disk space, no swap though. It needs to accept large file uploads (possibly GB) via a web interface. Most web servers I've come across handle a large POST request by holding all the streamed data in memory, my CGI app then moving it to disk. Are there any web servers out there that handle large POST requests by streaming them on to disk, rather than requiring the memory, or am I going to have to go down the route of using an application to directly handle the file upload http stream?

I still wish to maintain the CGI interface the application code is already using, so an all-in-one server and app is out of the question. It should also be free...

Thanks all!

Answer (score 0):

Also this product: http://uweb.workware.net.au/ which supports mmap() to accept POST requests of unlimited size, backed by disk rather than physical memory. [Disclosure: My company develops and sells this product]